# how to add 'global wait' to mocha test

Tags: electron, mocha.js, spectron

[image]

I'm trying to test my electron app with spectron and mocha;my application will close the first window after user login,so i need add some "wait action" to wait the second window to appear. But it seems setTimeout's callback works abnormal.

Answer (score 0):

I think the settimeout function works asynchronous, so the promise chain will continue after you started the settimeout. So somehow you have to await the settimeout - have you tried wrapping it in a promise, and then return the promise?

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   setTimeout(async () => {
      await this.app.client.windowByIndex(0); //I'm not even sure you need to await this
      resolve();
   }, 3000);
});
```